# Conceptual Model vs Logical Model vs Canonical Model

Tags: database, database-design, rdbms

What is the difference between Conceptual Model vs Logical Model vs Canonical Model in Database (RDBMS) perspective ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I learned it, a long time ago.

The concepual model is database neutral, and results from data analysis.  The ER model is good for this purpose.

The logical model is specific to a class of databases, such as relational databases.  It results from logical design. It holds only features of sigficance to users and programmers.  The relational is good for this when the project is to build a relational database.

The physical model is specific to a partcular database, like Oracle.  It includes features normally invisible to progammers, although it may have a dramatic impact on performance.

The next step is a creation script.

There are many other 3 tiered models, like ANSI SPARC.